# Disqus Comment System - margin left offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, disqus

I need to increase the margin-left on comments that are parents (comments that are replies).
The margin left is now 46px, 58px etc.

Is there some way to set the margin-left disqus should offset comments with?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer through script**

If you mean comments on comments on comments, you can use the following method, which has an offset of 46 + 12 for each parent.

```
$(".comment:not(.changed)").each(function(){
    $(this).addClass("changed");
    var parents = $(this).parents(".comments");
    $(this).css("marginLeft", 46 + ( parents.length * 12));
});
```

**Answer through CSS**

If you got a static amount of comments, you can use css

```
.comment{ margin-left: 46px; }
.comment .comment{ margin-left: 58px; }
.comment .comment .comment{ margin-left: 70px; }
```

**Best solution**

But it's better to nest them, so you can just use `margin-left: 12px;` and the nested already moved 12px and now his margin will be there aswell. So moved another 12px.

Then the HTML will ook like:

```
<ul>
    <li>COMMENT
        <ul>
            <li>COMMENT

                <ul>...ETC</ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS:

```
ul{ margin-left: 12px; }
```

Comment: I have already done something like that (the javascript). But the problem is when I click "load more comments". The new comments won't get the offset.

Comment: Updated the script function, after you added new comments, just recall the method.

Comment: It kinda works but the disqus callback function for pagination (this.callbacks.onPaginate) doesn't seem to work. The new comments doesn't get any offset. I guess it's because it's called before the html is rendered. But I don't know how to fix this. Here is my code so far: http://jsfiddle.net/wb3jf/